# How to force the Entity Framework 5 DbContext to re-read connection strings from app.config?

Tags: connection-string, entity-framework-5

I am trying to allow users to type in the data source into a dialog which I am then writing to the app.config for the application. The scenario I am having a problem with works like this:

1) User types the data source into my dialog and the dialog adds or updates the connection string. In this scenario the user typed the wrong data source the first time.

2) The user then opens the dialog that has the EF code (which inits the connection string stuff) and EF throws an exception that it cannot connect.

3) The user goes back into the original dialog and puts the correct data source name in and the app.config is again updated.

4) The user the opens again the dialog that triggers the EF code and EF still has the old data source in there although it is correct now in the app.config.

I have tried 
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings").

I have tried running 
    MyEFContainer.Database.Initialize() as well.

Neither seems to work. What do I need to do to have EF refresh the connection string data without forcing the user to close and reopen the app? If they do that then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would always work with a connection string in memory. Keep it e.g. in a context factory. Initially you read it from the config file, but it may get replaced by a new one. You store the new one in the app.config (when it is valid) for the next run of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Are you instantiating a new instance of the DbContext class after the connection string is corrected?  Reusing the DbContext instance that initially failed would be the problem.

Comment: Yes every time my form loads I new it up. Each time the form closes I Dispose().

Answer (score 0):

For the moment,I think to force EF to reload app.config .After we change the app.config the

```
 ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("xxx")
```

is not worked for EF,so you must to restart your application.

The best way to solve the problem:
with NO Connection strings in app.config.

[Uses automatic migrations and 2 databases using the same context. The real runtime supplied Connection. Approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504465/entityframework-code-first-custom-connection-string-and-migrations/16133150#16133150).