# Entity Framework Migrations with a different Database

Tags: entity-framework

I am stuck trying to figure out how to set the database to run a migration on.

I have created a new empty project and set up Entity Framework using code first. I have all my  classes built.

I want to add a new database and run the migrations on this. I have Migrations working but I can't figure out what database they are running on.

Is it possible to set the database you want to use for the migrations?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple DBs for the same context gets a little tricky. But It is possible:
The essence of the problem is how EF decides which connection to use.
It will access instantiate  the context without NO PARAMS during migration.
So depending on how that behaves influences you outcome and success.

Start here:
[EntityFramework code-first custom connection string and migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504465/entityframework-code-first-custom-connection-string-and-migrations)