# Entity Framework 6 - Database schema is not updating

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am learning EF
I wanted to play with the different types of inheritance using code first.

I initially started off with a few classes and ran my application. I saw the database get created with all my classes represented as tables.

However, when I add new classes or fields and run the application again, I do not see the changes in my database schema.

I have used the "DropCreateDatabaseAlways", so I don't understand why my database is not being updated with the proper schema as I add fields and classes. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Initial Code:

```
namespace Domain
{
    public class Good
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double BaseValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class Manufacturer {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public ICollection<ManufacturingCapability> ManufacturingCapabilities { get; set; }
    }

    public class ManufacturingCapability {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ManufacturingInput> Inputs { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ManufacturingOutput> Outputs { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan CycleTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class ManufacturingInput {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Good Good { get; set; }
        public uint Quantity { get; set; }
    }

    public class ManufacturingOutput {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Good Good { get; set; }
        public uint Quantity { get; set; }
    }

    public class ManufacturingDbContext :DbContext {

        public DbSet<Good> Goods { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Manufacturer> Manufacturers { get; set; }

        public ManufacturingDbContext() : base("name=EFLearnConnectionString") {
            Database.SetInitializer<ManufacturingDbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ManufacturingDbContext>());
        }
    }
}

namespace EFLearning {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            using (var manufacturingDbContext = new ManufacturingDbContext()) {
                var good = new Good() { Name = "Water" };

                manufacturingDbContext.Goods.Add(good);
                manufacturingDbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Database Tables in Management Studio after running:
[image]

Added code:

```
public class Station : Manufacturer {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Vector3 Location { get; set; }
}
```

and I added this to context:

```
public DbSet<Station> Stations { get; set; }
```

Database Tables in Management Studio after running:
[image]

Comment: Have you added a migration? http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: When you debug are you hitting the initializer code? BTW, I would move your initializer to a static constructor - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727585/database-setinitializer-to-null-not-working-entity-framework-4-3-1-code-first#16727643). Double check your connect string then I would try removing the database and see if that works.  @HansKilian Migrations are not needed if he is using an initializer. In fact, in early development I prefer initializers and seeding over migrations.

Comment: Yes, the initializer gets hit. If I remove the database through management studio, the log in that EF is going to use disappears too, no? When I intialiity set it up, I created a blank database and created a user for EF to use. On the first run, it created the tables I had as classes at the time. But subsequent runs do nothing to the schema.

Comment: If I delete the database and run the program. The database is recreated, but I still see no Stations table or field called Location. The Name field is there though. Also, I can add a field of type string and call it Poop, and then that shows up. So, I assume it doesn't know how to create the a Field for the Vector3.

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy for domain design to station and manufactor entity is Table per Hierarchy.so stations properties are now in manufactors table.
go to this [link](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) for more information.

if you you want Station entity have a seperate table must use of Table per Type 
go to this [link](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt) for Table per Type

Comment: So is Table per Hierarchy the default and will the physical table always be named after the base? Because I haven't set up anything to dictate the inheritance strategy yet.

Comment: Also, I looked and the columns for station's fields are not present in the manufacturers table. I will update the screenshot to show this in the OP

Comment: You don’t have to do anything special in Code First to enable TPH. It's the default inheritance mapping strategy