# Entity Framework - Check for pending migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In our production environment, we have an automated deploy script that takes down our site, runs migrations, and then brings it back online. We'd like to avoid taking the site down by just switching to the new code when there aren't any migrations that need to be run.

Does entity framework have a command like "Update-Database" that would allow us to check if there are migrations to run?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `DbMigrator` class has the `GetPendingMigrations` method which sounds like the exact one you look for. It should be something like

```
YourMigrationsConfiguration cfg = new YourMigrationsConfiguration(); 
cfg.TargetDatabase = 
   new DbConnectionInfo( 
      theConnectionString, 
      "provider" );

DbMigrator dbMigrator = new DbMigrator( cfg );
if ( dbMigrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any() )
{
   // there are pending migrations
   // do whatever you want, for example
   dbMigrator.Update(); 
}
```

Comment: I've not got around to implementing this yet, but that looks just like what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I use `DbContext.Database.CompatibleWithModel()`  with EF 6.1.3

Comment: In case of manually added migration steps (e.g. an enum value has changed and you might apply a script to update the corresponding field in the database) `DbContext.Database.CompatibleWithModel()` will return `true`. That doesn't match the original request!