# How to connect to more than one database with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have to build an mvc application which connects to two different database.
i need to have a menu say Employees > Which will open a create Employee page which need to be 
connected to Employee database (sql)and all the other menus/pages whould point to another database.

Can any one help me with the best approach with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 4.

Comment: you can either, in code, have it change the connection string of your context or have 1 DB where SPROC's are being called and IT can co-ordinate which DB and tables to hit. you could also have multiple contexts one for each DB but maybe difficult to maintain and easy to mess up.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a model for each database, each one having it's own entities, connection string and so on. In EF 6 you can even use the same context to host multiple database models.

http://olivierhelin.com/blog/entity-framework/entity-framework-6-one-entity-data-model-multiple-databases-2

[Using entity framework on multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941225/using-entity-framework-on-multiple-databases)

Comment: how would it work on "Code First" from database instead of  EF Designer from database