# Repository Pattern with Entity Framework and MVC4 Building Dynamic Connection String

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, repository-pattern, dbcontext

I am facing an issue while implementing the Repository Pattern [UoW] for MVC4 with EF6.

Error: 'XX.DataAccess.Context' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'XX.DataAccess.WriteRepository'

```
//Data Access layer Class for Saving/Deleting/Retriving etc. Inherits WriteRepository
public class Common : WriteRepository<Context>, ICommon
{
    //Method
}

//Repository Pattern
public abstract class WriteRepository<TContext> : IWriteRepository where TContext : DbContext, new()
{
    private readonly TContext _context;

    protected TContext Context { get { return _context; } }

    protected WriteRepository()
    {
        _context = new TContext();
    }

//Save Method

//Delete Method

//Retrive Method

//Find Method
}
```

//DB Context Class
   //Here i need to build dynamic connection string which takes the Client ID as the Parameter. If i use it in the parameter it gives me the error for Data Access method implementations which is mentioned above.

```
public partial class Context : DbContext
{
    static Context ()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Context>(null);
    }

    public Context (int ClientID = 0)
        : base(ConnectionString(ClientID))
    {
        var objContext = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
        objContext.CommandTimeout = 180;
    }

//DBSet's

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    //Mapping
}

private static string ConnectionString(int ClientID = 0)
    {
    //return connection string
}
}
```

Let me know what changes do i need to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `new()` constraint on `WriteRepository`. The constraint cannot be satisfied because `Context` does not have an zero-argument constructor, since you need to pass the `ClientID` in when you create it. Therefore, remove the `new()` constraint, and instead modify the `WriteRepository` constructor to take an argument of type `TContext`:

```
//Repository Pattern
public abstract class WriteRepository<TContext> : IWriteRepository where TContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly TContext _context;

    protected TContext Context { get { return _context; } }

    protected WriteRepository(TContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    //Save Method

    //Delete Method

    //Retrive Method

    //Find Method

}
```

Then, in the derived class, create the `Context` and pass it in as an argument to the base constructor.

```
//Data Access layer Class for Saving/Deleting/Retriving etc. Inherits WriteRepository
public class Common : WriteRepository<Context>, ICommon
{
    public Common(int clientID)
        :base(new Context(clientID))
    {

    }
}
```

Of course, any other classes that already derive from `WriteRepository` will need to be modified as well. I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @luksan. Thanks for helping. Actually if we specify this method, everytime ClientID will be 0. The objective is to send the Client ID from UI -> Business -> Data Access. This is a Multi Tenent DB and i want to know which Client is been Selected. Based on this Client i will be building the Dynamic Connection String which was mentioed in the Code above. Which i will get it from our Centralized DB [Have not implemented it in the code but its easier]. With the method you had given it will always be zero. What else can be done? Any idea?
    public Context ()
        : this(0)
    {

    }

Comment: Sorry, I had partly misunderstood your question. I've updated my answer to address the issue.

Comment: Hey @Luksan.. Thank you so much.. Solved :) Only one change in the code you mentioned.
public WriteRepository(int clientID):base(new Context(clientID))
To be changed to..
public Common (int clientID):base(new Context(clientID))

And it works perfectly fine.. :) Thx Bro...

Comment: Glad it worked ... please don't forget to upvote / accept my answers so that I get some points. ;-)