# Entity Framework DBContext Dynamic connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an application using **Entity Framework 6**.

I have project named **Data** where I have my `DbContext`.

```
public partial class MyDbContext: DbContext
    {
        
        static MyDbContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);

        }

        public MyDbContext()
            : base("Name=" + Utility.Constants.DbConnectionName)
        {

            Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
        }
}
```

Where `Utility.Constants.DbConnectionName = "TestConnection"`

In my web.config of course I have:

```
<add name="TestConnection" connectionString="Data Source=MYSERVERIPADDRESS;Initial Catalog=unitdb;User ID=sa;Password=12345;Connect Timeout=600;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Then I also have a project that is a Windows Service.

Inside that project I have a reference to my **Data** project so I have a access to my Entity Framework entities. Also in my Windows service project I have an `App.config` with the same connection string (above) because If not then it won't know where to get the data.

Is there I way I can set inside my Windows service project a connection string dynamically? Because my windows service may connect to a different database (of course that database has the same structure so EF can get the info).

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF6 DBContext Dynamic Connection String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165364/ef6-dbcontext-dynamic-connection-string)

Comment: create a constructor that takes a configuration name?

Comment: So instead a Name=something I can set the connection string in the constructor like: MyDBContext("Data Source=MYSERVERIPADDRESS;Initial Catalog=unitdb;User ID=sa;Password=12345;Connect Timeout=600;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient") ?