# Override DbContext connection string in repository and unit-of-work pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

We have an application that uses multiple databases for different users. We are using a generic repository and unit-of-work pattern and dependency injection. We have a `DbContext` which is a parameterized one. What we want is when users comes to our website, we want the `DbContext` point to their website for that particular transaction.

We tried registering the `DbContext` on the unity configuration and override it in the controller level. But that failed. Can anyone let us know how to get it done?

**DBContext**

```
public class TimperContext: IdentityDbContext<MyUser> 
{ 
    public TimperContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { } 
    public DbSet<UserAddress> UserAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your DBContext class?

Comment: `public class TimperContext: IdentityDbContext<MyUser>
    {
        
        public TimperContext(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<UserAddress> UserAddresses { get; set; }

        
    }`

Comment: Your question is quite vague and difficult to answer because we know very little information on how your system interacts with your DB. Since you are passing in the `Connection String` why can't you just use a different connectionstring for a particular transaction?

Comment: Hi, you question did not contain much info. By right this way should work; just need to make sure the connectionString format is correct.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467(v=vs.113).aspx  This may be what you want.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165364/ef6-dbcontext-dynamic-connection-string