# How to notify the user that Entity Framework Code First Migrations are being executed?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

Some of our Migrations take a considerable time to perform. So I am looking for a way to implement some kind of event or callback to notify the user interface that it should admonish the user to patience. I can write a custom event of course, but where do I place the handler for it?

Any pointer to some resources how to deal with this is very much appreciated!

Comment: What I think I didn't realize is whether you manually run migrations at a certain time you decide, or you have lots of databases, and you need an automation to block the user. If the second option is correct - then my answer should help. Just a trivial flag for each db and you are set.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put a flag on the database once the migrations start and unflag when process ends? That flag can easily be read in order to notify the user interface. Keep it simple...

**Here are some ideas when to raise the flag:**

- The "event" that can be used is the `InitializeDatabase` function, if you are using a custom initializer.
- If you are using a `DbMigrator` like I do, in order to manually performing migrations, you can just flag the database before initialization. 
  You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504465/entityframework-code-first-custom-connection-string-and-migrations) (my answer is down there) how to use `DbMigrator`.
- Another option is the `Up` function of the first migration (when using Automatic Migrations that might work - but it's a bit more tricky).

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by a 'Flag': is it some kind of global property or an event? How do I check if InitializeDatabase actually calls any 'Up' methods?

Comment: @Dabblernl - by `flag` I mean for a trivial boolean field in the database.. just put 0/1 in some field. Put 1 when the migrations start and read this from the UI to know whether the migrations had started.

Comment: @Dabblernl - Best would be to use a DbMigrator - you create it and than check if there are migrations using `GetPendingMigrations.Count` - if it's > 0 than you set the `flag` in the database. It's two lines of code.